# Converting JSON string into object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to convert a JSON string into an object in Objective C using the code:

```
NSString *jsonString = (NSString *) responseObject;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id  json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

The value of `jsonString` is

> "[{\"Date\": \"12-01-2015\",    \"Time\": \"7:00 am\",    \"Title\":
>   \"First Car Service\",    \"Details\": \"This was the first car
>   service ever done\"}]"

But the value of json is always nil. How do I convert the jsonString into a NSArray ?

Comment: what does the NSError object say?.... ah, nothing, as you pass in nil.

Comment: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7f81b3c3afe0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: I started using `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` in options, but now json is a NSString

Comment: for me the given example looks correct and is an array. Maybe it is polluted with some white spaces?

Comment: that there are some non-printable char present. try trimming the initial string.

Comment: I removed all whitespaces. The value of json is now a `__NSCFString` with value `[{"Date":"12-01-2015","Time":"7:00 am","Title":"First Car Service","Details":"This was the first car service ever done"}]`

Comment: dont do this fragment option: you have a complete json file there.

Comment: As soon as I switch that to `options:0`, the error is `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fee397b04c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: are the leading and trailing `"` in the jsonString?

Comment: Works now. I removed the leading and trailing `"` and replaced the `\"` with `"`

Comment: If you want to write that as an answer, I will accept

Comment: where do u get the json from? it is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My (third) bet: your json string isn't correct. If it contains the leading and trailing quotes strip them. Replaced the `\"` with `"`.

better: make the server or other json source send correct json.

Comment: The json is coming from the server. Unfortunately, I cannot control what's coming through

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it may be that your string is not formatted correctly, probably due to the quotes.

You should also make sure that after you have formatted the string, then you check the array has objects.

```
NSLog(@"JSON Details: %@", json[0][@"Details"]);
```

Comment: It gives a NSDictionary that is nil

Comment: I tried using NSJSONReadingAllowFragments, but that is returning a NSString

Comment: @WrightCS: nil stays nil, what ever type you gave it. and the given example should result in an array

Comment: If `json` is an `NSDictionary`, then why do you attempt to access index 0 in the `NSLog` statement? And setting the options for mutable containers has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Whright, with all your changes: nil is nil, no matter if it is typed NSDictionary, NSArray or id.

Comment: Changing `json` back to `id` doesn't affect anything. Based on your `NSLog`, `json` should be an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray` if you insist on the mutable containers option). But again, none of that has anything to do with the error.